# Return max value of column in single table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I've got a simple need to get the max value from one particular column (date) in one table only.

Here's the table with some sample data (using sql server 2000):

```
EMPLID            EFFDT                  EFF_STATUS   SUPPR_DDP_ADVICE
000619      2007-07-09 00:00:00.000 A   Y
000619      2008-04-04 00:00:00.000 A   Y
000619      2008-04-18 00:00:00.000 A   Y
000622      2013-06-21 00:00:00.000 A   Y
```

As there can be several `EFFDT` dates for each employee, I want to be able to get the MAX `EFFDT` for each employee.

I did try

```
SELECT  *
FROM    PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT
WHERE   EFFDT < (SELECT MAX(EFFDT) FROM PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT)
AND SUPPR_DDP_ADVICE = 'Y'
```

but that still gave me duplicates, and not returning the max EFFDT date).
Appreciate assistance

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT a INNER JOIN (SELECT EMPLID, MAX(EFFDT) as MaxDate FROM PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT GROUP BY EMPLID) b ON a.EMPLID = b.EMPLID and a.EFFDT = b.MaxDate
WHERE SUPPR_DDP_ADVICE = 'Y'
```

The where clause might need to go into the select for the results set that is joined onto

Comment: Great, this looks very good.  Thanks you for the quick assistance/reply!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EMPLID,EFFDT
FROM(SELECT  EMPLID,
             EFFDT,        
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLID ORDER BY EFFDT DESC) AS number
     FROM PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT) a
WHERE   number = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For this I would do the following:

```
SELECT EMPLID, MAX(EFFDT)
FROM PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT
WHERE SUPPR_DDP_ADVICE = 'Y'
GROUP BY EMPLID
ORDER BY EMPLID
```

I was not sure whether the suppr_ddp_advice was coming from another table or not, however this should work for your case.